# Confusing scoping of bolding in beamer

Tags: beamer, bold, math-fonts, bugs

I'm not sure if I've happened on a bug or am merely misunderstanding how some font commands in latex ought to behave. The following is a heavily minimized example that produces a bolded "tt" while I would expect it to be a teletyped "tt":

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathit{}\mathsf{}\mathtt{tt}\text{}\mathbf{}$
\end{document}
```

No errors or warnings are reported during compilation.
One can commute `mathit` and `mathsf` (but removing either or removing `text` or `mathbf` causes the bolding to vanish). I cannot reproduce this after switching the document class to article nor after removing `newpxmath`.

Is there a comprehensible explanation for this behavior? Is it a bug (and if so, where should it be reported)?

(Experiments conducted with pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) and kpathsea version 6.3.4 on an Ubuntu machine.)

Comment: Looking in the log file, one can see a lot of warnings for `LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape OT1/cmss/b/n in size <6.1> not available
(Font)              Font shape OT1/cmss/bx/n tried instead on input line 7.`. The font combinations you want to use are not available so some other shapes are used. At the end of chain, the result happens to be bold.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I see, I can understand how the font shapes aren't available, but it still surprises me that removing commands that I would expect to be irrelevant (such as the `\text{}` _after_ the `\mathtt{tt}`) impacts the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reproduce this without `beamer`

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsa}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsb}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsc}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsd}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\usepackage{newpxmath}

%\setcounter{localmathalphabets}{0}
\begin{document}
$\mathit{}\mathsf{}\mathtt{tt}\text{}\mathbf{}$
\end{document}
```

disabling the local math alphabets feature by uncommenting the `\setcounter` avoids the issue.

This indicates the problem is in the base latex format code, related to but not identical to

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1101